# How can I open new activity by clicking on image?

Tags: android

I have created an app using Recyclerview and Firebase,there i am adding name,image and some description. I want to open a new activity by clicking Imageview which shows full description and image.I have used many codes,of which everyone is leading to app crash.I have been trying it for more than one week, Now i am feeling helpless.Help me Out,Please!

my Github repository link :- github.com/anask1104/ProjectView

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");

    findViewById(R.id.post_image).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Scrolling.class);
            ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this,findViewById(R.id.post_image),"myImage");

            startActivity(intent, optionsCompat.toBundle());


        }
    });




    mBloglist = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.blog_list);
    mBloglist.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mBloglist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}
```

Comment: The error messages you got from the crash could be helpful

Comment: Please post your error logcat.

Comment: here is my Github repository link :- github.com/anask1104/ProjectView

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.anask1104gmail.projectview, PID: 6134
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo